# there is a function in python i am not understanding

Tags: python, python-3.x, subdomain

```
        link_regx = re.compile('<cite.*?>(.*?)<\/cite>')
        try:
            links_list = link_regx.findall(resp)
            for link in links_list:
                link = re.sub('<span.*>', '', link)
```

what is 
compile() and  sub()
function use here

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> **re.compile(pattern, flags=0)**
>
> Compile a regular expression pattern into a regular expression object, which can be used for matching using its match(), search() and other methods.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.compile

> **re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)**
>
> Return the string obtained by replacing the leftmost non-overlapping occurrences of pattern in string by the replacement repl.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub

Comment: i am asking  re.compile with  <cite.*?

Comment: It defines a pattern which attempts to match any text that is in between a `<cite>` tag and a `</cite>` tag.  Check out this page for a detailed breakdown of teh regex: https://regex101.com/r/B4kRMi/1

Comment: If my answer helped you (or at least got you closer to your goal :-)), please accept it.